# RejectedExecutionException when loading bitmaps for ListView with asyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-bitmap

I'm trying to create a ListView with bitmaps that are generated on demand. I'm using https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-BitmapCache to cache the bitmaps

I'm using a SimpleAdapter, with this :

```
setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
 @Override
 public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object object,String string) {
     if( string.startsWith("ClassName:") ){
         final ImageView yourImageView=(ImageView) view;
         AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> imageLoadAsyncTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
             String cname;
             @Override
             protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... classnames) {
                 cname=classnames[0];
                 return db.getCharIcon(classnames[0]);
             }

             @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                 yourImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
             }
         };
         imageLoadAsyncTask.execute(string.substring(TextUtils.getTrimmedLength("ClassName:")));
         return true;
     }
     return false;
    }
}
```

the getCharIcon function is here :

```
Bitmap getCharIcon(String classname){
    Bitmap modBmp;
    CacheableBitmapDrawable cacheBmp=mCache.get(classname);
    if(cacheBmp==null)
    {
        modBmp=createCharIcon(classname);
        mCache.put(classname,modBmp);
    }
    else
    {
        modBmp=cacheBmp.getBitmap();
    }
    return modBmp;
}
```

where createCharIcon generates the bitmap this way (I have yet to implement the final version that selects the good portion of the image):

```
Bitmap createCharIcon(String classname)
{
    Bitmap modBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBmp,0,0,60,60);
    return modBmp;
}
```

Sadly I am getting this error :

```
07-02 14:13:04.248  11592-11592/com.lectem.gecharacters E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1876)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:774)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1295)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:394)
            at com.lectem.gecharacters.CharFragment$1.setViewValue(CharFragment.java:110)
            at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:168)
            at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
            at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1730)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:655)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1287)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1573)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1252)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1241)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1252)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1128)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1045)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get this error when I scroll the list back too fast, so I suppose it is linked with the number of asyncTasks I can use...
I'm really not sure if this is how I should do it or not, but the library bitmapLruCache needs to be ran on something else than the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, that error means that you are trying to use too many `AsyncTasks` at once. In an `AdapterView`, this can occur if you are forking an `AsyncTask` for every item (e.g., every row in a `ListView`) without taking into account row recycling, and the user flings the list.

Quoting [the library's documentation](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-BitmapCache):

> If you wish for the library and recycling feature to work, you MUST use the bundled CacheableImageView wherever possible.

Since you appear to be using this in an `AdapterView`, please make sure that you are using `CacheableImageView`.

Comment: It would seem to be the right thing to do but if I change

    final ImageView yourImageView=(ImageView) view;

to 

final CacheableImageView yourImageView=(CacheableImageView) view; 

it throws the exception java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView

Comment: @Lectem: You need to also change your layout, or wherever that `ImageView` is being created, to use `CacheableImageView`. Or, switch to a library like Picasso that does not require a custom `ImageView` class to handle this case.

Comment: I did try changing the layout, but I get an error, as it is not recognized... I think I will simply deactivate the disk caching.
I did take a look at Picasso but it seemed a bit harder to use it for my purpose.
Maybe I should take a closer look...

Comment: @Lectem: "I get an error, as it is not recognized" -- make sure that you fully-qualify the class name in the XML element (`<uk.co.senab.bitmapcache.CacheableImageView>`).

Comment: Seems to be working, but I still get the RejectedExecutionException.
I can afford not using the diskcache but it would be interesting to find a solution though